# Sonar Javascript plugin errors: "Fail to decorate" and "does not contain any file in its source folders"

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I don't know how to resolve this after searching for hours:

I am using Sonar 3.2 with Jenkins and just installed Sonar Javascript plugin without doing any configuration. The Jenkins job works properly with Java analysis, but when I put language=js, it will trigger errors below.

I read some docs on the Sonar Runner and Maven example but I don't know how that would translate to configuring a Javascript project on Jenkins for Sonar support. Do I have to modify my pom.xml? Am I required to have JsTestDriver in order to use this plugin?

Error log in Jenkins:

Embedded error: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.Project@39d2b175[id=103,key=PROJECT.KEY:javascript,qualifier=TRK]'
Project "SAMPLE PROJECT" does not contain any file in its source folders:
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/{JENKINS JOB NAME}/workspace/src/main/java

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.Project@39d2b175[id=103,key=project.key:javascript,qualifier=TRK]'
at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:84)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:70)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.execute(DecoratorsExecutor.java:55)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:94)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:139)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:131)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:121)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:121)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:73)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:60)
at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:150)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:98)
... 21 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Project "SONAR PROJECT NAME" does not contain any file in its source folders:
- /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/{JENKINS JOB NAME}/workspace/src/main/java
Please check your project configuration.
at org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator.checkRootProjectHasFiles(FilesDecorator.java:75)
at org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator.decorate(FilesDecorator.java:64)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:79)
... 36 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that the error message is clear enough: Sonar looks for Javascript sources in "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/{JENKINS JOB NAME}/workspace/**src/main/java**" folder.

=> you must set the value of the "sources" property to match the base folder of your JS scripts (or the base folder of your Web application if you have several places where the JS files are).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove/exclude that file which is creating decorate error during execution.
edit in sonar-project.properties file 
    add -->  sonar.exclusions=